# Euler's Analysis Infinitorum, Bk.1, art.1

Tags: analysis, definition

I just started reading Euler's Analysis Infinitorum Book 1 and am already stuck on the first article: a definition of "constant quantity." It reads as follows:

1. A constant quantity is a determined quantity which always keeps the same value.

For the sake of convenience, call the first phrase in this definition, "a determined quantity," A; and call the second phrase, "which always keeps the same value," B.

My question: Does B include A? In other words, if I tell you that I am talking about a quantity "which always keeps the same value," then is this quantity determined? (I'm assuming that by the word determined, Euler means: known already, or can be known (theoretically or otherwise) from the available data.) I think it is, because a quantity "which always keeps the same value" must:

-Have a value;

-Be something that is unchanging.

In other words, it has a value that is unchanging, and is therefore theoretically well-determined, hence determined.

This would lead me to believe that the definition could be reduced to,

1. A constant quantity is a quantity which always keeps the same value,

were this not Euler; the fact that it is Euler makes me slightly hesitant in accepting that he would add a redundant word ("determined") to his definition.

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect it just has to do with translation.

[Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E101.html) has the original Latin text:

> Quantitas constans est quantitas determinata perpetuo eundum valorem
>   servans.

Google translates the statement as:

> A constant quantity is determined by constantly keeping the same
>   value.

I'm not very good with Latin, so I can't verify. I do have friends that know more about it, so I may ask them and update this answer if I learn anything new.

Either way, the particular version you are reading has decided to translate it a bit differently. I wouldn't get too hung up on it as long as you can make out which are the constants in the rest of the book, but I do appreciate your scrutiny.

**UPDATE:**
A trusted friend from classical studies gave me the following translation:

> A consistent/constant quantity is defined as a quantity preserving
>   the same value forever.

He said some other things about predicate adjectives and nominatives, but in the end it seems that your idea and Euler's Latin line up.

Answer (score 0):

Really, I think a better translation of determinata here is "fixed", and what Euler wrote simply says

A constant quantity is a fixed quantity, always keeping the same value.